# What is the purpose of the last bits in the 2-qubit-operation Toffoli implementation?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

What is the purpose of these quantum gates?

They're appended to the circuit after the value has been computed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In[13]:= H = 1/Sqrt[2]*{{1, 1}, {1, -1}};
T = {{1, 0}, {0, Exp[I*Pi/4]}};
CNOT = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], T].CNOT.
    KroneckerProduct[T,ConjugateTranspose[T]].CNOT // MatrixForm


{"1", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "1", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "1", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "I"}
```

So that red boxed region just serves to act as multiplication by $i$ when the first two qubits are $1$.

So what remains must be acting by $-i X$ on the third qubit when both the first two are $1$.

In fact so it is, by assuming the first two qubits are $1$ and computing the resulting $2$ by $2$ operator on the third qubit. That is the $U$ for the summand $P_1 \otimes P_1 \otimes U$ when writing the full operator as $P_0 \otimes P_0 \otimes U_{00} + P_0 \otimes P_1 \otimes U_{01} \cdots$.

Plug into Mathematica again:

```
H.PauliMatrix[1].ConjugateTranspose[T].
PauliMatrix[1].T.PauliMatrix[1].
ConjugateTranspose[T].PauliMatrix[1].T.H // MatrixForm
```

And it checks out.

If you didn't have the boxed part it would be $-iX$ controlled on the first two, instead of $X$ controlled on the first two.

Comment: When I run the following command on Python, I end up with a result of [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]] rather than the identity matrix:

np.kron(np.identity(2),T) * CNOT * np.kron(T, T_dag) * CNOT

Comment: Elementwise vs matrix multiplication